# Remove lines around an HTML table in Gutenberg block

Tags: html

A client grabbed a HTML form from PayPal to accept donations on his site. He dropped it into an HTML block on his WordPress site.

In the site, lines are appearing around the table for some reason. The table looks normal when rendering in a typical HTML file, and I can't figure out why the Gutenberg block is adding these lines.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="FGJNN7ME6FQSP">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Subscription">Subscription</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="Base">Base : $40.00 USD - monthly</option>
    <option value="Supporter">Supporter : $60.00 USD - monthly</option>
    <option value="Sustainer">Sustainer : $80.00 USD - monthly</option>
    <option value="Benefactor">Benefactor : $100.00 USD - monthly</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

And here how it's rendering on the WordPress site:

[image: subscription PayPal table]

Why are the gray lines appearing around the table, and how do I remove them?

Comment: Gutenberg isn’t adding anything. This would just be your theme’s CSS for tables. You could add your own CSS to the Customiser to style this table how you want.

Comment: I didn't realize it was the theme adding the CSS. Thanks.

I just added inline CSS to the HTML block to solve the problem:
```<table style="border:none">```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize it was the theme adding the CSS. I just added inline CSS to the HTML block to solve the problem: `<table style="border:none">`